# Mapping between a finite set and the set of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis

In one of the exercise I'm doing, I have to prove that some finite set is countable. Yet in the same book the definition of countability of a set A is that there exists a 1-to-1 mapping of A onto the set J of natural numbers. How can this be possible?

[image]

Comment: You can't.  Some books include finite sets as countable and some do not.  The definition you have shown excludes them.  You can show there is an injection of a finite set into the naturals, but not a bijection with them.  You have understood the concept, which is the important thing.

Comment: According to this books definition that is a contradiction.  Finite is "at most countable".  However many text (I think most but I don't have the numbers to back me) consider "countable" to mean either "finite" (after all you *can* count a finite set, can't you) or "countably infinite".  This book seems to have inconsistently mixed the two.  Assume the book meant "at most countable".

Comment: "In one of the exercise I'm doing, I have to prove that some finite set is countable."  Can you quote the *exact* problem.  If you know the set is finite then by definition is "at most countable".  Are you sure the set *is* finite?  Or is that part of what you need to show?

Comment: Here's the problem being typed out:

Let X be a metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point. Prove that 
X is separable. Hint: Fix $\delta > 0$, and pick $x_1 \in X$. Having chosen $x_1,...,x_j \in X$, choose $x_{j+1} \in X$, if possible, so that $d(x_i,x_{j+1}) \geq \delta$, for $i=1,...,j$. Show that this process must stop after a finite number of steps, and that X can therefore be covered by finitely many neighborhoods of radius $\delta$. Take $\delta = 1/n (n = 1, 2, 3...)$ and consider the centers of the corresponding neighborhoods.

Comment: If we follow the hint, then as δ→0, E grows in size. If E is the set that we need to find, then I can see here that this procedure could potentially make E infinite and we might be able to prove the countability of E. But because of the property of X (which is also mentioned in the hint), I assume E is always finite?

Comment: I prefer  "countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite" so that  "uncountable" is synonymous with "not countable".

Comment: I was considering the problem yesterday, and I realized that the set $E$ is the countable union of finite sets, i.e. $E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{1/n}$, where $1/n$ is the radius $\delta$ mentioned in the process. So my task now is to find a 1-1 correspondence between this set $E$ and the set of natural numbers. I'm thinking about lying them out in lines. Let $e_{nm}$ be the $m^{th}$ element of $E_{1/n}$, we'd have:

$e_{11}$, ..., $e_{1j}$ |--line break--|

$e_{21}$, ..., $e_{2j}$, ..., $e_{2k}$ |--line break--|

$e_{31}$, ..., $e_{3j}$, ..., $e_{3k}$, ..., $e_{3l}$

Comment: Now we can just let $1 \mapsto e_{11}$, ..., $j \mapsto e_{1j}$, $(j+1) \mapsto e_{21}$, ..., $(j+j) \mapsto e_{2j}$,..., $(j+k) \mapsto e_{2k}$, ..., while deleting duplicating entries as necessary, and we'd have the desired bijection. Is this an acceptable answer?